# fluent-ffmpeg ffmpeg exited with code 1: Unknown decoder 'h264_nvenc'

Tags: ffmpeg

```
      import { ipcMain } from "electron"
      import fluentFfmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg"
      import ffmpegStaticElectron from "ffmpeg-static-electron"
      import ffprobeStaticElectron from "ffprobe-static-electron"

      const ffmpeg = fluentFfmpeg()
      ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegStaticElectron.path)
      ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobeStaticElectron.path)

      ffmpeg
        .input('0.mp4')
        .inputOption([
          "-hwaccel cuvid",
          // "-hwaccel_device 1",
          "-c:v h264_cuvid",
          "-c:v h264_nvenc",
        ])
        // .videoCodec("h264_nvenc")
        .outputOptions([
          '-map 0',
          '-f hls',
          '-hls_time 5',
          '-segment_time 5',
          '-hls_list_size 0',
          '-hls_segment_filename',
          `${tsFilePath}/%d.ts`
        ])
        .output(`${m3u8FilePath}/${name}.m3u8`)
        .on('start', (commandLine) => {
        })
        .on('error', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.log(err, stdout, stderr)
        })
        .on('progress', (progress) => {

        })
        .on('end', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      
          
        })
        .run()
```

ffmpeg -codecs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZSqL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7NxT.png)
Sorry, my English is not very good!

I want ffmpeg to use GPU hardware acceleration. The above is my code, but it has been executing incorrectly. This problem has plagued me for several days. I hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: `"-c:v h264_nvenc"` should be in outputOptions

Comment: 谢谢 我发现是 ffmpeg.exe 版本过低，已经解决。